# Maven Properties not referenced in properties file

Tags: maven, properties

I have some properties in my maven pom.xml.

```
<properties>
    <number>3</number>
    <age>38</age>
</properties>
```

(They are random properties)

In a properties file, lets call it resource.properties, I have the following:

```
value1 = ${number}
value2 = ${age}
```

When spring tries to read properties from this file, it cannot get the reference from `${number}` saying that it cannot be found.

Why is this and how can I make it work? Or is doing this not possible at all.

EDIT: I have enabled filtering but still does not work. My resource is in the `src/test/resources` directory.

Here is the part of the pom where I enable filtering.

```
<build>
...
<resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>       
  </resources>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tell maven which files it uses to replace placeholders e.g

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
```

see [maven filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for me. Do i put what u posted in the <build><resources>? Or somewhere else?

Comment: nevermind, I had to use testresources instead of resources, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should enable resource filtering for the maven resources plugin as shown below:

```
  ...
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  ...
```

See the [Maven Resources Plugin section about filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for details.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for me. Do i put what u posted in the <build><resources>? Or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, <build><resources>, you may need to issue mvn clean test